# Problem with Uri.EscapeUriString() regarding accented characters

Tags: c#, url, .net-4.0, uri

If I try to put a URL in the function with accented characters, like "Percepção", it outputs "Percep%C3%A7%C3%A3o", which doesn't work correctly. However, "Percep%e7%e3o" does work the way it should.

```
String Result = Uri.EscapeUriString("Percepção");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed this issue by encoding the original string to ASCII bytes first, and then encoding it back to UTF8.

```
String Result = Uri.EscapeUriString(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Percepção")));
```

Thanks to binarycoder for some more details.

Comment: Be aware the `Uri.EscapeUriString()` does not escape `&` nor `=` nor `?`, nor any RFC reserved characters. That means you would break your URL if your query params contained any of those characters. So it seems `Uri.EscapeDataString()` is the method to use.

Answer (score 7):

The string is first encoded as UTF-8 and then the bytes are turned into literal characters or percent-encoded sequences.

This can be seen by comparing the result of `EscapeUriString` to:

```
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Percepção")));
// 50-65-72-63-65-70-C3-A7-C3-A3-6F
```

The standard is [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), which states:

> When a new URI scheme defines a component that represents textual data consisting of characters from the Universal Character Set [UCS], the data should first be encoded as octets according to the UTF-8 character encoding [STD63]; then only those octets that do not correspond to characters in the unreserved set should be percent-encoded.

(As an aside, note that `Uri.EscapeDataString` is often more appropriate to use than `Uri.EscapeUriString`.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have fixed this issue, see my answer to this question.

Comment: Are you sure about using Uri.EscapeDataString? This suggests that you shouldn't : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yangxind/archive/2006/11/09/don-t-use-net-system-uri-unescapedatastring-in-url-decoding.aspx

Comment: @GordonThompson That article is saying don't use `*Unescape*DataString()`, not `EscapeDataString()`. In fact, near the end of the article, they recommend using `EscapeDataString()` instead of `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`.

Answer (score 0):

The last way I get it working. Use this function

```
   Function UriEncode(ByVal cText As String) As String
      Dim cRes As String = ""
      For Each iBy As Byte In Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(cText)
         Select Case iBy
            Case Asc("%")
               cRes &= "%25"
            Case Asc(" ")
               cRes &= "+"
            Case Is > 127
               cRes &= "%" & Hex(iBy)
            Case Else
               cRes &= Convert.ToChar(iBy)
         End Select
      Next
      Return cRes
   End Function
```

If you launch:

```
   MsgBox(UriEncode("Percepção"))
```

You will get

```
   Percep%E7%E3o
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["params"] != null) {
    param = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["params"].ToString()).ToString();                    
}
```

GOOD SOLUTION!!

Comment: Could you clarify your answer here please?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is relevant to my original question.