# Windows Phone - WebBrowserTask special characters issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, escaping, browser, windows-phone, character

I am doing this :

```
WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
task.URL = Uri.EscapeDataString("http://m.asd.com/search.html?q=" + "Çerez adını verdiğimiz");
task.Show();
```

But the browser shows:

[image]

`EscapeDataString` makes "ı" appear but not for "ğ" and "ç".

How can I solve this problem?

I tried this solution but it didn't help:

[Problem with Uri.EscapeUriString() regarding accented characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354324/problem-with-uri-escapeuristring-regarding-accented-characters)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

task.URL is deprecated. Use task.Uri. Worked for google search for me.

```
task.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + "Çerez adını verdiğimiz");
```

Hope it helps.