# Internet Explorer url issue with speical characters

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a angular application with asp.net web api2 backend.

Url: https://myapp.test.com/world-news/Cura%C3%A7ao

The above url works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari but has an issue with IE browser.

The value : Cura%C3%A7ao when sent to the web api backend is interpreted as Curaçao for Chrome and Firefox,Safari but for IE browser it is interpreted as Cura�ao.

Here in this case the above string contains as special character: ç which is interpreted as �.

Can anyone help me to know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
String result = Uri.EscapeUriString(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Curaçao")));
```

Be aware of the Uri.EscapeUriString() does not escape & nor = nor ?, nor any RFC reserved characters. That means you would break your URL if your query params contained any of those characters. So it seems Uri.EscapeDataString() is the method to use.

Source: [Problem with Uri.EscapeUriString() regarding accented characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354324/problem-with-uri-escapeuristring-regarding-accented-characters)

Comment: Thanks emert117 for you response. I tried the above but it did not worked for me. I am not sure why the request from IE browse is sending Cura�ao to the web api but whereas the Chrome and Firefox, Safari browser are sending Curaçao to the web api backend.

Comment: I tried to use decodeURIComponent API in the angular code and was able to decode the special character  � to ç but sill on the API end I am seeing it as �. Any help on this is much appreciated.